# CSS on ajax call is working in desktop but not in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have made an ajax call where on beforeSend I am calling a function which loads CSS classes to create a loader and overlay. and on success, I am removing it by calling another function. But the CSS classes which are being called is getting applied only in the desktop view and not mobile view. I am not sure what mistake I am doing in this? Can anybody let me know how I can resolve this?

The ajax call is as below

```
function filterAjax(s_url){         
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data : {is_ajax:1},
            url: s_url,
            beforeSend: function() {
                initLoader();
            },
            success: function(data) {
                killLoader();               
                updatePage(data);
                filter();
                $(".offcanvas-siderbars").removeClass("column-left-active");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });     
    }
```

The functions which are being called are as below.

```
function initLoader() {
        $('.mkmage-overlay').fadeIn(200, function(){
            $('.mkmage-loader').show();
        });
    }

    function killLoader() {
        $('.mkmage-loader').hide();
        $('.mkmage-overlay').fadeOut(200);
    }
```

The CSS classes that I am using are as below.

```
.mkmage-overlay{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: #363636;
    z-index: 10000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.mkmage-loader{
    display: none;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1000000;
    transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0)
}
```

Comment: use `return false;` after ajax call

Comment: Hi @Bhargav tried it, but it didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: there any error or whats the other problem

Comment: @Bhargav There is no error, As I mentioned in the question the same CSS that is working in the desktop is not working in the mobile view

Comment: because  some mobile browser dont support jquery thats why

Comment: how do you define `not working`? is the loader does not show? or the class does not applied? and I don't see any connection `initLoader` and `killLoader` with adding and removing classes. also where is the `.offcanvas-siderbars` located in the HTML as that is the only add/remove class that exists, looks like the `.offcanvas-siderbars` is a desktop only element

Comment: @Bhargav I have checked in all the browsers and its the same everywhere.

Comment: @am05mhz We are creating the overlay and loader by calling the initloader and we are removing it using the jquery fadeout by using the killloader function. even if we consider the .offcanvas-sidebars and desktop only element where we remove the class. at least the initloader should have been initialized in the desktop as we have not associated it with any particular element.

Comment: err, not sure what you are trying to say, isn't that there is nothing wrong in the desktop, and you still did not say what is the problem with the mobile, what do you call `working` is?

Comment: @am05mhz I followed the hint that you had given. Actually, the div with the classes that I have mentioned above was hidden in the navigation bar and hence they were not visible on the main screen. I have moved them to the main screen and the CSS is working properly now. Can you leave your suggestion as an answer so that I can accept that? Thank you.

Comment: posted an answer of it, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the poster had commented, the problem was because of the position of `.offcanvas-siderbars` in the HTML that was in another element that is only visible in the desktop mode, so it would be hidden in mobile mode.

happy to help ;)